# Conditions for continuity of composition

Tags: general-topology

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$, $g:Z \rightarrow Y$, and $h:Z \rightarrow X$ be functions such that $f \circ h = g$, where $X, Y$ and $Z$ are topological spaces. What are some weak conditions that we must place on $g$ and $f$ to guarantee that $h$ is continuous? If possible, what are the $\textit{weakest}$ conditions? How would we modify if the question were to be directed toward $h,g$ for continuity of $f$, and similarly, if directed toward $f,h$ for continuity of $g$. This question grew out of curiosity while studying about covering spaces and liftings.

I would like to add that the first question concerns me more than the latter two. The latter two are just extras, if you can provide answers for them. This post is primarily about the first question.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the topology on $X$ is the smallest topology that makes $f$ continuous. ie. the sets $\{f^{-1}(U) : U \subset Y \text{ open}\}$ generate it. Then, it would suffice to know that $g$ is continuous because
$$
g^{-1}(U) = h^{-1}(f^{-1}(U))
$$
would be open for all $U \subset Y$ open. Hence, $h^{-1}(V)$ would be open for all $V \subset X$ open.

I suspect this is the weakest condition needed, but that needs a proof, and I need some sleep :)

Answer (score 0):

About continuity of $f$:

Let it be that the topology on $X$ is 'coinduced' by $h$, i.e. $U\subseteq X$ is open iff $h^{-1}(U)$ is open in $Z$. Then $f$ is continuous iff $g=f\circ h$ is continuous.

About continuity of $h$:

Let it be that the topology on $X$ is 'induced' by $f$, i.e. $U\subseteq X$ is open iff $U=f^{-1}(V)$ for some $V$ open in $Y$. Then $h$ is continuous iff $g=f\circ h$ is continuous.